# MPMoviePlayerController doesnot play the video its full length

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using the MPMoviePlayerController to open a video file.The video runs fine.But suppose if the video file is 10 sec ,with 1 sec remaining the video stops.Is that its natural way of playing or should we specify something.The follow is the code used

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:location];

self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:self.moviePlayerController];

self.moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
self.moviePlayerController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
[self.moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
[self.moviePlayerController.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayerController.view];

- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification {

NSNumber *finishReason = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey];

if ([finishReason intValue] != MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded) {
    self.moviePlayerController = [notification object];
    self.moviePlayerController.view.hidden = YES;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:self.moviePlayerController];

    [self.moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.moviePlayerController release];
}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Comment: It always plays full time for me. Please try to play it in your Mac.

Comment: Yiur question is missing the info on which devices and iOS versions you have tested this.

Comment: I've never experienced that behavior.  I've written several apps that play video.

Comment: On your code it play full video. please chk your video.

Comment: I checked on Ipad 3 version 6.1.3

Comment: Your video encoding is obviously broken - fix it on that side.